# Why is this initialization to a static pointer not valid?

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a macro to initialize fields of a complex structure. In this structure, some member is a pointer which I want to initialize sometimes with a real address and sometimes to `NULL`.
The structure can be simplified as follows:

```
typedef struct {
int * p;
} MYSTRUCT;
```

My first pass at the macro was:

```
#define INIT_STRUCT(x) {&(x)}
```

and the usage would be:

```
static int foo;
static MYSTRUCT struct1 = INIT_STRUCT(foo);
```

This works well when I initialize to a real pointer, but the following does not work:

```
static MYSTRUCT struct2 = INIT_STRUCT(NULL);
```

because it is developed as `{&(NULL)}` and the compiler (justifiably) flags having & on a constant as an error.
I know that I could choose to have the & as part of the argument and not part of the macro body, but this is not convenient in my case, and also I cannot accept that the compiler wins, so I tried to be smarter with the following second version of the macro:

```
static void * NOTHING;
#define INIT_STRUCT(x) {&NOTHING == &(x) ? NULL : &(x)}
```

with usage

```
MYSTRUCT struct1 = INIT_STRUCT(foo);
MYSTRUCT struct2 = INIT_STRUCT(NOTHING);
```

However the compiler protests that "initializer is not a constant".
If I replace `&NOTHING == &(x)` by `1 == 2`, there is no error, so the format of a condition is not the problem.
On the other hand, `&NOTHING` and `&(foo)` are valid as initializers by themselves.

Is the compiler correct in invalidating my "smarter" macro?
Is there any other solution, except writing the & as part of the argument for foo?

The compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio C 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Why not simply define the `INIT_STRUCT` macro as `#define INIT_STRUCT(x) {(x)}`, and use it as `INIT_STRUCT(&foo)`? It will be more transparent to the readers of the code what's happening, and of course would solve your problem with using `NULL`.

Comment: In addition to what @Someprogrammerdude said, you could also define 2 macros; one for common case, and one for special case. Getting too "smart" with macros should be avoided, as macros are not very flexible, and can cause other problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and use this.

```
#define INIT_STRUCT(str, x) {str -> p = x}
```

This is used as

```
INIT_STRUCT(struct1, foo);
INIT_STRUCT(struct2, NULL);
```

Comment: This is assignment, not initialization. As such, it won't work on `const` variables.